# Module does not show up in blocks (6.x)

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules, block

I have a module that I've activated, but it does not show up in the disabled blocks list.

The module is named "My Module"

Inside the my_module folder I have:
my_module.module
my_module.info

my_module.info:

```
name = My Module
description = My module description.
core = 6.x
package = My Modules
```

my_module.module

```
<?php
function hook_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()){
    switch ($op) {
        case 'list':
            $block = array();
            //List out all blocks you want to create here
            $block[0]["info"] = t('Display info'); 
            break;  
        case 'view':    
            switch ($delta) {
            case 0:
                     $block['subject'] = "ADMIN Header of the block";
                     global $user;
                     if(in_array('Site admin', array_values($user->roles) || $user->uid == 1)){

                    $block['content'] = "input form";
                    $block['subject'] = "Header of the block";
                }

            break;
            }
    }           
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning any values in your hook call.  You'll need to return the array for it to be displayed. I also never tend to use `break;` when writing implementations of hook_block either.

Try removing the `break;` and adding `return $block;` at the end of both cases.

e.g

```
 case 'list':
        $block = array();
        //List out all blocks you want to create here
        $block[0]["info"] = t('Display info'); 
        return $block;
```

and

```
case 'view':    
        switch ($delta) {
        case 0:
                 $block['subject'] = "ADMIN Header of the block";
                 global $user;
                 if(in_array('Site admin', array_values($user->roles) || $user->uid == 1)){

                $block['content'] = "input form";
                $block['subject'] = "Header of the block";
            }

        return $block;
```

I'm sure you've seen it, but this might be beneficial to others http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_block/6

Comment: There's no real need with hook_block as far as I know.  I always use break; if I have logic in my switch blocks, but in this instance, you need to execute each part of the switch.

Sorry if it makes little sense...it's too close to the end of my working day ;-)